# (My)SQL Basics and much more

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've been using MySQL for quite some time now. Most of that time I used it with PHP, for Joomla development. Up until now, I didn't pay very much attention to optimization, since I was usually asked to finish stuff ASAP.

Now, while I know that ASAP factor is a reality, I would like to improve my knowledge of relational DBs, together with good introspection to query and db optimization. I'm planning to start working with some rather large dbs, for which my usual approach will not be possible.

Any recommendations for some good books from the area?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I get a lot of **ASAP** requests, too. One thing I know about MySql: it is not free of bugs. We had an issue where the `Command.Timeout = 0` had no affect (documented in the latest release of MySql). Having a DBA on site would help with any optimizations but I know we aren't all afforded that luxury...if I could have only one wish it might just be that we could get a DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Joe Celko's SQL for smarties, 4th ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123820227)

[The Art Of SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008945)

[Refactoring SQL Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514972)

I would not recommend you to devote yourself to MySQL only. Instead, if you can, try to gain some experience with other DBMSs, where the advanced optimizers make your job easier.

Comment: Thank you Marco, I reckon that you provided info about general-enough books (not mysql-only)

Comment: yes, but the last one explicitly compares mysql-oracle-sql server and how they behave according to several optimizations, with charts and the like (relative measurements only)

Comment: I might just get *Refactoring SQL Applications* since I work with both MySql and SqlServer.

Answer (score 1):

If using linux shell I recommend `mtop` application to watch what is happening.

In mysql configuration you can specify logging slow queries:
http://www.webdevelopmentstuff.com/112/optimizing-mysql-log-slow-queries.html

There also is a parameter that defines what is a long query. Set it to 0 when desperate :) I once had when debugging a CMS that kept sending thousands of requests that took 0.00001s each.

I also found this: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

And I recommend a bit of reading on indexes.

For php+mysql with slow-queries log it's also useful to know Apache Bench command:
`ab -c10 -n50 http://...` calls the adress 50 times with up to 10 concurrent request.

That's just a list of tips. It's not complete in any way.

Comment: thank you, i'm using ubuntu at home, so i'll check things out over there.